# Link ARMv7 library to ARMv7s app

Tags: iphone, ipad, linker, armv7

According to the literature, an A6 processor will execute ARMv7 code. My project is failing at link because a library was built for ARMv7, but the application is built for ARMv7s.

A typical message is (when I attach my iPad 4 (Retina) or iPhone 5):

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/ssl/iphoneos/lib//fipscanister.o, file was built for armv7 which is not the architecture being linked (armv7s): /usr/local/ssl/iphoneos/lib//fipscanister.o
ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/ssl/iphoneos/lib//libcrypto.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7s): /usr/local/ssl/iphoneos/lib//libcrypto.a

Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s:
  "_FIPS_incore_fingerprint", referenced from:
      _FINGERPRINT_premain in fips_premain.o
  "_FIPS_signature", referenced from:
      _FINGERPRINT_premain in fips_premain.o
  "_FIPS_text_start", referenced from:
      _FINGERPRINT_premain in fips_premain.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7s
```

I know I can resolve this by removing ARMv7s from Valid Architectures (VALID_ARCHS), but I'm not sure why since the A6 processor can execute A5 object code. Or I can perform an additional build of the library for the ARMv7s architecture, but that's more work and requires a different on-disk directory structure.

Is there any magic to link an ARMv7 library with an ARMv7s application?

Comment: I guess your lib is compiled for (armv6 & armv7) and main project with (armv7 & armv7s)..just replace lib with (armv7 & armv7s)...problem solve...!

Comment: A processor being able to execute backward-compatible code doesn't mean that the linker can handle all versions of the generated code as well. Either recompile that "FIPS" library for armv7s, or disable armv7s.

Comment: Thanks @Raj - No, I built one library - ARMv7 (not ARMv6 and ARMv7). It was build using iPhoneOS6.0 SDK.

Comment: Thanks @H2CO3 - to be technically correct, both the FIPS Object Module (FIPS library in you term) and the FIPS Capable library was built with ARMv7. FIPS Capable is actually the library, and uses the object code  from FIPS Object Module. Sorry to be pedantic

Comment: Thanks @H2CO3 - "Either recompile that "FIPS" library for armv7s, or disable armv7s". I'm trying to avoid that, but I agree the linker might have a knowledge gap. I think I'll try to get to the bottom of that over at the BinUtils mailing list.

Comment: Are you sure... are you using the latest repository 1.0.1c (libaries with support for armv7, armv7s) https://github.com/st3fan/ios-openssl?

Comment: You can also.. try to Building (support) for armv6 in Xcode 4.5 http://blog.chpwn.com/post/31824877081

Comment: Thanks @TonyMkenu. OpenSSL only has limited support for iOS at the moment. This morning, I got everything working (FIPS Object Module and FIPS Capable Library). I needed one check-in to fix a problem, and Dr. Henson was kind enough to oblige (http://cvs.openssl.org/chngview?cn=23221). I'll be giving my work back to the OpenSSL Foundation this week. I know Steve in the business office is looking forward to full support  on Apple platforms.

Comment: (removed architecture tag, as question isn't really architecture-specific)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Jim Grosbach on the [Xcode mailing list](http://lists.apple.com/archives/xcode-users/2013/Jan/msg00135.html), the linker switch `-allow_sub_type_mismatches` should allow `ld` to proceed with linking. And from Apple's [`ld` man pages](http://lists.apple.com/archives/xcode-users/2013/Jan/msg00135.html):

```
 -allow_sub_type_mismatches
             Normally the linker considers different cpu-subtype for ARM
             (e.g. armv4t and armv6) to be different different architec-
             tures that cannot be mixed at build time.  This option
             relaxes that requirement, allowing you to mix object files
             compiled for different ARM subtypes.
```

There's also a [Changelog entry](http://opensource.apple.com/source/ld64/ld64-97.2/ChangeLog) that details the environmental variable called `LD_ALLOW_CPU_SUBTYPE_MISMATCHES`.

However, I found `-allow_sub_type_mismatches` simply did not work on Xcode 4.5.2. Grepping the web reveals a few Apple RADAR's for `-allow_sub_type_mismatches`. See, for example, radar://6134468.

Hopefully its fixed by now, but nothing surprises me when it comes to Apple and their defective software.